# Strip Unicode from List Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to strip off [u'] from the below list.

```
[u'Wireless Internet', u'Air Condition', u'Wardrobe', u'Television', u'In House Movies', u'Flatscreen TV']
```

And show the below values in my django template

```
Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe
```

The unicode was originated when saving MultipleChoiceField values.

Models

```
class MyRooms(models.Model):
  #other fields
  room_amenities=models.TextField()

  def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.room_name, self.id)

room_amenities= forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ROOM_CHOICES, required= False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I tried encode to 'utf-8' but its not working due to AttributeError. I also iterate over the list by writing a custom template filter it's not working. It's returning `None` in django template.

For the custom template tag I wrote,

```
register = template.Library()

 def strip_u(value):
     thin=list(map(str, value))
     return thin

 register.filter("strip_u", strip_u)
```

The output is

```
['[', 'u', "'", 'W', 'i', 'r', 'e', 'l', 'e', 's', 's', ' ', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'e', 't', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'A', 'i', 'r', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'i', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'W', 'a', 'r', 'd', 'r', 'o', 'b', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'T', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'v', 'i', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'I', 'n', ' ', 'H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'i', 'e', 's', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'F', 'l', 'a', 't', 's', 'c', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'T', 'V', "'", ']']
```

How do I go about this?

UPDATE: According to Bakkal's solution. I did this:

```
{% for myroom in myrooms %}

<p> {{myroom.room_name}}</p>
<ul>
    {% for amenity in myroom.room_amenities  %}
        <li>{{amenity}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

And the output is

```
[
u
'
W
i
r
e
l
e
s
s
I
n
t
e
r
n
e
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt and its output here?

Comment: Yeah.. the problem is stripping off the [u']. That's what I need.

Comment: Okay.. how do I display it without the accents in template?

Comment: Do you have a `Room` model? Does it have an `amenities` field? If yes, what is the type of that field? If you used a `CharField` or `TextField`, then something might be coercing the list type to string.

Comment: Yeah I have a room model and the field is a textfield. I've updated my question. But I'm yet to get your solution like this line: room.amenities = amanities. How do you come about 'amanties'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show the below values in my django template
>
> Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe

**The answer I was afraid to give, because it's not really practical or best practice to save that kind of representation into the database, but since you revealed `Room.amenities` is a string:**

```
>>> s = "[u'Wireless Internet', u'Air Condition', u'Wardrobe', u'Television', u'In House Movies', u'Flatscreen TV']"
>>> ', '.join([str(x) for x in eval(s)])
'Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe, Television, In House Movies, Flatscreen TV'
```

The above takes the string representation you have, and gives the string representation you want. Does the job you want but it's really not recommended. `eval()` is dangerous, you can lookup the security implications.

**The better way would be to process that when you save the model, so that you don't need to process this each time you display it (not recommended, but may be necessary if you don't want to use DB relationships or `ArrayField`**

You have using a [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield), which gives its result as a list of unicode objects.

So the direct output from that form field is like below an actual list, so let's not try and turn that into a string in Python.
Keep it as it is, then you can process the format you want

```
>>> amenities = [u'Wireless Internet', u'Air Condition', u'Wardrobe', u'Television', u'In House Movies', u'Flatscreen TV']
>>> ', '.join([str(x) for x in amenities])
'Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe, Television, In House Movies, Flatscreen TV'
```

Then you can save it to the model

```
room.amenities = ', '.join([str(x) for x in amenities])
room.save()
```

**Even betters ways to explore (Recommended)**

You could use a relationship, you'd have `Room` model, then each `Room` would have zero, or many `RoomAmenity` objects associated with it. read more on [Django Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
class Room:
    ...
    amenities = models.ManyToManyField(RoomAmenity)


class RoomAmenity:
   name = CharField()
   def __unicode__(self): # use __str__ in Python 3
       return self.name
```

Then in template

```
{% for amenity in room.amenities %}
    {{amenity}}
{% endfor %}
```

You could use `ArrayField` and store each amenity as an element in the `room.amenities` list field. This is possible on PostgreSQL e.g., see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield), it may be possible for the DB you are using too.

> Is there a way I can make it display like dis `<li> wireless internet </li> <li> Air Condition </li>`? hope u get my point?

If you're not ready to use the recommended way to store the amenities as a relation or a list, you can also pull the string representation and parse the items out of it like below:

```
>>> 'Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe'.split(',')
['Wireless Internet', ' Air Condition', ' Wardrobe']
```

Now you have a list that you can pass to the template and iterate through to display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It will save like like 
  Wireless Internet, Air Condition, Wardrobe, Television, In House Movies, Flatscreen TV. Is there a way I can make it display like dis <li> wireless internet </li> <li> Air Condition </li> ? hope u get my point?

Comment: @YoYo There, I think I covered both the recommended and the hackish ways. If you have time you should go with relationships or list storage in DB. Hope this helped, have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would love to use the save() method. But fixing it through views is very tedious and not easy because I will have to edit a whole lot of code. I'm thinking if it would be okay to do it in models save method?

Comment: Also I'm using Mysql.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Will mark this as answer because it solves part of the problem but I'm still facing issues. Like when I used  ', '.join([str(x) for x in amenities])  in views, it worked wth a model and failed with another. I want a way where I can save amenities like dat and filter it properly with custom template tag. That will be better. But eval() issues won't let me due to security issues. But it would have been the best method for me.